# character_set_database not updating on mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, utf-8

so I followed the "tutorial" here:

```
http://outofcontrol.ca/blog/comments/change-mysql-5.5-default-character-set-to-utf8
```

And after doing so, the mysql 5.7 servers on linux updated properly and everything is showing as I would expect.

BUT, I did the same on my development machine, Macbook Pro, El Capitan, and I see the following:

```
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
**character_set_database    latin1**
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        utf8
character_set_system        utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/local/mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64/share/charsets/
```

Why is this still latin1? The other entries updated to utf8 and this worked on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`character_set_database` is of virtually no use.  Don't worry about it.

When creating a table, explicitly state

```
CREATE TABLE (...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

That helps you avoid various changes to defaults that may occur now or in the future.

Actually, the future is likely to be `utf8mb4` with collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

As long as you are going to 5.7, you may as well go to that combo.  utf8mb4 lets you get to Emoji and the rest of the Chinese character set; the *520* collation is arguably "more correct".

The link you gave is a bit weak -- it does not explain how to convert any data you have.

Existing tables are *not* changed by changing the settings you mentioned.

So, what is the whole picture?  Do you have existing data?  In utf8 or latin1?  Are you updating in place?  Or dumping and reloading?  Etc.

Comment: I'm dumping and reimporting. The arabic characters kept messing up one of  my other processes (turns out I was missing a clause in my query to keep it to english). So I don't have to worry about existing data.

The link I gave just explained why I had an error when I used so many of the answers given on SO regarding utf8 encoding and I was still getting ????? for all arabic characters.

Comment: Look for "multiple question marks" in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1766831%20question%20marks